# Delphi 7 - Why doesn't VK_RETURN work for me?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

```
procedure TfrmProgress.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
 Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    if key = VK_RETURN then
    begin
        Self.Close;
    end;
end;
```

And then I press Enter and nothing happens...

Comment: Your question was downvoted because you gave us a piece of code that only you know what it does (e.g., what is `Progress`?) without explaining it. In addition, it would seem like the problem is that the code isn't running at all, and so the question "What is wrong with this code?" isn't a valid question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't tell you what your problem is from this information, but I can tell you how to work it out.

Create an event handler and attach it to `Application.OnMessage`. This will get called whenever any queued message is pulled of your apps message queue. Keyboard messages are input messages and thus queued so the WM_KEYDOWN message will arrive in this event handler.

Implement the handler like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.ApplicationMessage(var Msg: TMsg; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.Message=WM_KEYDOWN then
    Handled := False;
end;
```

Enable Debug DCUs and then set a break point on the `Handled := False` line. Run your app, select the spin edit and press ENTER. The code will break and you can now step through to see where the WM_KEYDOWN message is routed.

After the event handler returns you should step until you find a call to DispatchMessage. Press F7 to step into this and keep following the trail until you can find out where it lands and why it doesn't land in your intended event handler.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me track the problem.

Comment: could you tell us what the problem was?

Comment: @David the main application was already using that key for something else, and I was creating the dialog within the application.

Comment: @John: You could easily have found out yourself that the problem with the code was that, in fact, it was never executed at all. All you had to do was to put a breakpoint on the `if key = ...` line (simply by clicking the ruler to the left of the code), and notice that the breakpoint didn't pause the program when you pressed Enter.

Comment: @Andreas Right, and you're commenting here why exactly? By the way, breakpoint did help me diagnose the problem at all.

Comment: @John: People keep trying to help you, and you keep insisting on being rude to them. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if you haven't already done so, especially the section on how to treat others. It's really a bad idea to be inconsiderate to people you're asking for help, and it discourages them from trying to do so. This community works by being polite and respectful; if you can't work within those guidelines, perhaps you should look elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: @John: I was commenting here because I wanted to share with you the insight about how great the integrated debugger is. When I write JavaScript (very seldom, but it happens), and it doesn't work, usually I have no idea why. But when I write Delphi applications, I can use the integrated debugger to pinpoint the problem almost effortlessly. I can set breakpoints on lines to be notifiyed when they execute, I can step the code line by line, and I can watch the value of variables while doing so. I can even set conditional breakpoints, see the call stack, and read the CPU registers/RAM during run.

Comment: (cont.) It is really an invaluable tool, and I wanted to share it with you, so that you also can benefit from it. Now, text-based communication is tricky. When talking face-to-face, there is seldom any ambiguity or interference in the communication, but in text-based communication, you can interpret a message in many different ways. I see that you could have interpreted my messages in a offensive way, but trust me -- that wasn't intentional. On the contrary, being a teacher, I have rather strong instincts to teach things, and sometimes people don't realise that and just think I am being rude.

Comment: @Andreas I understand the usage of debugger, however it did not provide the help I needed, can't you understand that? Nonetheless thank you for the effort of informing me. And the first two posts you addressed to me sounded more like criticizing rather than helping.

Comment: @John: "Holding your breath trying to be as calm as possible?" Well, try a little harder. The only one being rude and accusatory is you. Please don't bother to response to this, I won't bite...

Answer (score 4):

The focus may be in an edit control, so in order for the Form to get its hands on the keyboard input, you need to set the KeyPreview property to True. Did you do that?

Answer (score 1):

After you press Enter and the form does not close, does it close *eventually* when the processing has finished? I.e., does it close with a "delayed effect"?

It might be that your form is not processing messages while the operation you're showing progress for continues.

One solution is to periodically call Application.ProcessMessages within your main processing routine. However, do not close the form in the OnKeyDown event. Instead, set a flag such as "AbortRequest := true", and check that flag in your processing routine, and if it is set, exit from there, and then close the form. This will allow you to do any necessary cleanup before aborting.

Other than that, is the spinedit enabled and focused? If you put a breakpoint in the event, is it triggered?

Another possibility: VK_RETURN could be consumed by another control or component on the form. For instance, if you already have a TAction on the form with Enter as its shortcut, the spinedit will never see that key. Or you might have a TButton with its Default property set to True - same result.

All in all, we probably do not have enough information to know for sure.

Answer (score -2):

I personally do not like that you close the form within the editor's KeyDown event handler.  I would suggest that you do this at some other moment, at least delay this call by posting a custom message to the form and call the Close method within this message handler.  Anyway, such code works fine on my machine.  I only do not know what are you doing by calling the Progress method.  I would suggest that you put a breakpoint in this event handler and check how the program works.  If you are interested in the post message approach, just let me know  and I will post the code here.

Comment: There's already a built in mechanism to do this posting that you describe. It's called Release. It calls Free rather than Close, but so long as you don't have an OnCloseQuery handler then it comes to the same thing.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's at most a very long comment; it provides no help to solving the poster's problem whatsoever. "It works on my machine"?